# Name 'TexturedSurface' is not defined

Tags: python, animation, textures, manim

I need to create a textured 3D model of Earth in manim, and there is a "TexturedSurface" function in documentation

```
from manim import *

class SurfaceExample(Scene):
    CONFIG = {
        "camera_class": ThreeDCamera,
    }

    def construct(self):

        sphere = Sphere(radius=3)
        day_texture = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Whole_world_-_land_and_oceans.jpg/1280px-Whole_world_-_land_and_oceans.jpg"
        surfaces = [TexturedMobject(sphere, day_texture)]
```

But when I try to run this code, I have only " name 'TexturedSurface' is not defined" error

How can I solve it?

I use manim v 0.18.0

In the current documentation, I couldn't find a section on texturing at all

Comment: When I try to run this, it complains about `Sphere` being undefined.  Are there `import`s you are using that haven't identified in your question?

Comment: Yea, I imported manim

Comment: Are you using the community manim? `TexturedSurface` is only in the 3b1b version.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I am using Community manim, so, I need to install 3b1b